# how to get the meta name keywords -vba

Tags: vba, excel, parsing, html-parsing, getelementsbytagname

I am trying to get the meta name keywords from a [webpage](http://www.amazon.in/dp/0751537535/)

> meta name="keywords" content="Mitch Albom,For One More Day,Little, Brown Book Group,0751537535,Fiction / General,General & Literary Fiction,Modern & contemporary fiction (post c 1945),USA

I need to get the contents from it need help.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetData()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    Dim str As String
    Dim wk As Worksheet
    Dim webpage As New HTMLDocument
    Dim item As HTMLHtmlElement

    Set wk = Sheet1
    str = wk.Range("Link").value
    ie.Visible = True

    ie.Navigate str

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    Set Doc = ie.Document

    Dim kwd As String
    kwd = Trim(Doc.getElementsByTagName("keywords").innerText)
    MsgBox kwd

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do that is by finding meta-element with name *keyword* and referring to its `content` property. You can do it like that:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetData()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    Dim str As String
    Dim wk As Worksheet
    Dim webpage As New HTMLDocument
    Dim item As HTMLHtmlElement

    Set wk = Sheet1
    str = wk.Range("Link").value
    ie.Visible = True

    ie.Navigate str

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE


    'Find the proper meta element --------------
    Const META_TAG As String = "META"
    Const META_NAME As String = "keywords"
    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    Dim metaElements As Object
    Dim element As Object
    Dim kwd As String


    Set Doc = ie.Document
    Set metaElements = Doc.all.tags(META_TAG)

    For Each element In metaElements
        If element.Name = META_NAME Then
            kwd = element.Content
        End If
    Next

    MsgBox kwd

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) You are awesome