# Getting meta property from a URL

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to get the price of product from URL and it has

```
<meta property="product:price:amount" content="47.2" />
```

I tried the following to get it but it does not work

```
Set price = ie.Document.querySelector("product:price:amount")
worksheet.Cells(i, "D").Value = price.innerText
```

As well as

```
Set Doc = ie.Document
Set metaElements = Doc.all.tags(meta_tag)

   For Each element In metaElements

    If element.name = meta_name Then
    keywd = element.Content
    wks.Cells(i, "C").Value = keywd
    End If

   Next
```

Comment: Well the price (47.2) isn't an object so you can assign it.. do you want to declare a `Double` and and assign the "content" attribute?

Comment: How can I get the price 47.2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get the meta name keywords -vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357705/how-to-get-the-meta-name-keywords-vba)

Comment: What did you assign to meta_tag and meta_name variables?

Comment: Documents is already loaded (`Debug.Print ie:Document.body`  shows the html)? If not wait till loaded.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options but if you want to refer to `product...`; that is the value of the attribute `property`, so you would need an attribute = value css selector. Attribute selectors are denoted by `[]`. Furthermore, to avoid confusing with psuedo class selector syntax the value of the attribute, which contains `:`, must be entirely encased within `''`.

```
ie.document.querySelector("meta[property='product:price:amount']").Content
```

Comment: Why I get Nothing on price but when I do the similar Set price = ie.Document.querySelector("meta[property='product:price:amount']")
        wks.Cells(i, "D").Value = price.Content I get the amount?

Comment: what do you mean nothing on price?

Comment: The variable price has not a value inside

Comment: there is no innerText to the tag. The price is in the content attribute of the element.

Answer (score 0):

I think since this piece of the html is not an object or element you wont be able to use this method (the object would have a div and an id or class property that you could search for). What you would need to do is find the element this is in and access it that way. Something like this: `ie.document.getElementsByClassName("class name like Product info or something maybe")(0).getElementsByTagName("meta").textcontent`

Note: `.textcontent` is faster and unformatted unlike `.innertext`

if a div does not have an id or class property then it is a child and you will have to navigate from the parent using `.Children(0)` and/or `.nextElementSibling`

This website has a lot of good information that would help I would look here since without more of the html I am unable to help:

http://automatetheweb.net/common-vba-methods-properties-web-automation/

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get the meta tags:

```
Dim metaElements
Set metaElements = ie.Document.GetElementsByTagName("meta")
```

Then loop through them looking for the property:

```
Dim element
For Each element In metaElements
    If element.Name = "product:price:amount" Then
        Dim price 
        price = element.Content
    End If
Next
```